# How to custom RailsAdmin Export options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I would like to export an report, but can't figure out how can I custom the export options.

I have two resources in RailsAdmin as following

```
  class Shop < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :location

    RailsAdmin.config do |config|
      config.model Shop do
        export do
          field :name
        end
      end
    end

  end
```

And `Location`from which I want to export the report

```
  class Location < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :locations

      RailsAdmin.config do |config|
        config.model Location do
          export do
            field :address
            field :shops
          end
        end
      end

    end
```

When I export I get report as following all shops name in a single row

```
    Address              Name(Shop)
    "Address 1"          "Shop1, Shop2, Shop3, ...."
```

But I want something like this, iterate shops and display in single row

```
    Address              Name(Shop)
    "Address 1"          "Shop1"
    "Address 1"          "Shop2"
    "Address 1"          "Shop3"
```

Anyone can help? Search a lot through web did not get any idea.

Comment: check this one https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Export

Comment: I already read that wiki page, but my scenario is different, my one is has_many relation but that one is for belongs_to.

Comment: you can use `bindings[:object]` for customize your current behavior

Comment: Can you please add some code example, actually I am failed to iterate through bindings[:object].

Comment: just `puts bindings[:object].shops` and let me know what you get in it

Comment: I think you did not understand my question, I want to iterate shops in location.